# pseudo element :before or :after on an image element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

As far as I can tell you can't use :before or :after with text content on an image element? Is this correct? Am I missing something?

[http://jsfiddle.net/rcztz](http://jsfiddle.net/rcztz/)/

I know semantically this isn't correct, I'm using because I'm appending the src to the image using js, but if there's no src I'd like to display alternative content (I could use another div, but it would be nice to just use :after or :before)

Comment: are you using pure javascript or a library like jQuery or MooTools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. You are not able to use pseudo elements on images

Answer (score 1):

As lnrbob says, you cannot use pseudo elements on images. However, put a class on the image and use a background image and you'll be accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: I'm actually trying to use an icon-font with it. I don't mind rendering it as an image, but it would be nice not to have to.

Comment: Then use the ALT tag and apply a special "font-family" declaration on the image. It won't necessarily work in all browsers, but it should work. Or else just replace the non-existant image with your icon font code; you should be able to check if it loaded via javascript.

Comment: using the `alt` attribute is a good idea but bear in mind one of the browsers it won't work in is, unbelievably, Chrome. I tend to style my alt text more often than not but it only ever looks right on FF