# Using ::before or ::after on an image element?

Tags: css, image, pseudo-element

Do the "::before" and "::after" pseudo elements not work on image elements?

Here's an example I put together...I'm just trying to get a yellow background behind the image here:
http://dabblet.com/gist/3861878

I saw this "answered" (but no other details) in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846931/pseudo-element-before-or-after-on-an-image-element), but can't seem to find anything about it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS 2.1 spec says:

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html

So it it'd be wise to avoid using this. Behavior across the browsers is uncertain and can change in future.